Is it possible to resolve a vitest expect.poll before it reaches timeout time?
I have a basic vitest test like that:
      let error = false;
      provider.registerEventHandler('event_xxx', (pair:string) => {
        error = true;
      })
      
      await expect.poll(()=> {
        if (error) 
          throw new Error('An error ocurred.')
        else 
          return server.isEventQueueEmpty()
        
      },{interval:100, timeout:20000}).toBeTruthy()

I need to exit poll immediately as soon as I throw (I don't mind to use any other way).
With the current code an assertion is raised when an error occurss but it happens after timeout has ran out (after 20 seconds).
Is this possible?
